# access redux state to validate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a validation function that is in a seperate file outside of my component and I want to be able to access my redux store state to check if a value is valid or not but I am not able to access this state.

I have tried to access the store state by importing it into my validation.js file `'import store from '../../client'` but this doesn't work

How can I access store state in validation.js or is there a better way to handle validations like this with react/redux?

**client.jsx**

```
import "@babel/polyfill";

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
// import {registerObserver} from 'react-perf-devtool'
import $ from 'jquery';

import Layout from './components/Layout/Layout.jsx';
import './styles.js'

import configuratorReducer from './reducer/reducer.js';
import configuratorHandler from './handler/handler.js';
import configuratorInit    from './handler/init.js';

import getInitState from './init/initState.js';

const composeEnhancers =
  typeof window === 'object' &&
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
      maxAge: 500,
    }) : compose;

    const enhancer = composeEnhancers(
      applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware),
      // other store enhancers if any
    );

export const store = createStore(
  configuratorReducer,
  getInitState(),
  enhancer
);


configuratorInit(store);
store.subscribe(() => configuratorHandler.handle(store));

$(document).ready( () => {

  const app = document.getElementById('app');

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Layout />
    </Provider>
    , app
  );

});
```

**addToCart.jsx**

```
 class AddToCart extends React.Component {
     render() {
         return(
               <Wrap
        plissee={plissee}
        rollo={rollo}
        lamellen={lamellen}
        holzJalousie={holzJalousie}
        disabled={!this.props.isValid}
      >
         )
     }
 }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    amount: state.model.amount,
    designation: {
      ...mapDesignationName(state.model.designation.alias),
      alias: state.model.designation.alias
    },
    isValid: configuratorIsValid(state),
    adding: state.model.cart.loading,
    price: state.model.price,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({
    ...addToCartActions,
  }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddToCart);
```

**validation.jsx**

```
   export const operationLengthisValid = (state) => {
  return state.model.operationLength.value ? state.model.operationLength.isValid : null;
};

export const operationMotorPositionIsValid = (state) => {
  return state.model.operationMotorPosition.value ? state.model.operationMotorPosition.isValid : null;
};

export const operationHandlingIsValid = (state) => {
  return state.model.operationHandling.value ? state.model.operationHandling.isValid : null;
};

export const operationOpeningDirectionIsValid = (state) => {
  return state.model.operationOpeningDirection.value ? state.model.operationOpeningDirection.isValid : null;
};

export const configuratorIsValid = (state) => {
  const validations = [windowShapeIsValid, profileColorIsValid, operationTypeIsValid, dimensionIsValid, clothIsValid, fasteningIsValid];
  // rollo
  if (state.model.designation.id === 4) {
    validations.push(chainColorIsValid);
  }
  // lamellen
  if (state.model.designation.id === 5 && state.model.operationType.value === 'Kette und Zugschnur') {
    validations.push(operationLengthisValid,  operationOpeningDirectionIsValid, operationChildProofIsValid)
  }
  else if ((state.model.designation.id === 5 && state.model.operationType.value === 'Funkmotor')) {
    validations.push(operationMotorPositionIsValid, operationHandlingIsValid, operationOpeningDirectionIsValid)
  }


  return !!validations.reduce((prev, curr) => prev && curr(state), true);
```

Comment: You should just import your validations after making them export functions, and use them inside your reducers before passing the state on to be set again.

Comment: thank you for the answer could you please provide an example of how I might so this?

Comment: Where ever your reducers are, import the validations and use them inside the reducer on the state that comes in as a parameter, then you can return the new state after it has been through your validations.

Comment: `import validations from 'validations';

somReducerFunction(state, action) {
  if (action === '') {
    const newState = validation(state);

    return newState;
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided should work. 
The way you access the store when working with redux is, just as you did, by `connect`ing the component to the store, and calling methods if required.

I would note that, logic like that, should not be called as part of a component life-cycle.
React (flux) urges you to have components that reflect state, not mutate it.

I would recommend instead placing the logic as part of a reducer. 
Whenever that state change, re-trigger the validation logic, and set a `valid` state on the store, and bind your component to it.

Comment: thank you for the answer could you please provide an example of how I might so this?

Comment: Have you looked at the examples provided at redux's website? check it out at https://redux.js.org/basics/exampletodolist, it should be similar, if logic is supposed to happen on the state, then it should be executed within the reducers (in the attached example, look at the `TODO_TOGGLE` https://redux.js.org/basics/exampletodolist#reducers-todos-js